# Querying a list of items from a one-to-many relationship in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

If I have a class called Artist, which has many Song:

```
class Artist {
    String name
    static hasMany = [songs : Song]
}

class Song {
    String title
    Integer duration
}
```

I want to know which artists sang a list of titles. For example I want to know the artists who sang `Hello`, `My Love`, and `Yesterday` (An array of String). What is the best way to do this?

I tried using [criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria) and findAll, but can't really figure out which is the best way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This HQL will work:

```
def artists = Artist.executeQuery(
   'select distinct a from Artist a join a.songs song where song.title in (:titles)',
   [titles: ['Hello', 'My Love', 'Yesterday']])
```

It will return a list of artists, but if there's only one result you can get it as `artists[0]`